# Appearance of Terminal and Nautilus in RDC

Tags: command-line, nautilus, themes

Hi Folks:  When I first set up my ubuntu system, and was using the local screen, keyboard and mouse, the terminal window and nautilus both had really good looking themes on them.  The machine is intended to run headless over the local area network and is accessed via RDC -- for some reason, the themes have vanished when I connect via RDC and the current ones are really ugly -- anyone know how I can fix this?

[image: Picture of my desktop on RDC]

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome tweaks

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open Tweaks-> Appearance -> Icons, select Yaru, or whatever you like.

Comment: Gnome tweaks can cause a lot of problems as people tend to change things they should not touch.